# Visual Flow and Dataloader

Tags: data-loader, visual-flows, data-synchronization

I am looking to implement a flow that analyzes incoming data file to perform the following actions:

1. create new related records for data file records (i.e. create a contact for an opportunity record);
2. identify which data file records are invalid, based on primary and related record comparison queries;
3. store and display invalid records in the form of an email or output file.

Rather than letting the data loader create the records at the time of upload, I want to know if there is any way, through Flows or any OOB data management tool, to first perform analysis and then prevent and/or allow a dataload file from creating or updating primary and related records.

Usecase: Perform data synchronization job with data file and salesforce enterprise org. Primary record = junction object for account(many-many) and contacts (1-many). Related records = account and contact records. Data file primarily mapped to junction object records, but has values relevant to related records.

Any ideas or tips to perform desired data synchronization?

Comment: Data Loader does DML; any flow that executes will occur after the DML is done

Comment: The only way I could think of doing this is creating a staging table as a custom object, loading data to there and having a flow process that data after it is loaded.

Comment: Data preparation is considered as a pre-requisite step for the Salesforce data loader. What type of analysis are you looking to perform on the incoming data?

Comment: thanks fro the comments. i know that is best practice to perform data transformation in an ETL tool or outside of Salesforce, but there is no budget for that. my current design involves a data file and PB-Masterflow-subflow to validate and update records. I didnt build a staging object nothing it was necessary, especially as we are looking to update existing records based external id match. Do any of you have a sound understanding of VF logic and mechanics? I am 75% done with solution but I am running into some walls in my subflow. Any help appreciated.